# Is deleting something Islamic okay?

Tags: practical-islam, ayah

I am also user here and always answer some questions if needed. I also use a site which lets me download Qur'an ayah in image format. Now I have used it for answering purpose so the purpose is completed, Now I want to delete that Ayah.

Deleting a file means putting it in "recycle bin" and can I delete a ayah because it is like putting in recycle bin and I don't like to do that.

**Is it okay to delete an Ayah in image format?**

Comment: A computer recycle bin is not *really* a recycle bin, it's just called like that.

Comment: Yes it is not recycle bin and it's name bothers me when I delete an element.

Comment: I fully agree on that tho, BUT if you press shift + delete you can delete it permanently without it going thru the recycle bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with deleting a digital file containing Qur'an or hadith because the intention and the impressions are not to sacrilege them. Unlike the case in putting stuff with Qur'anic content in garbage, the digital content cannot also become exposed or taken to other places or situations where sacrilege could be possible.